# Why opening ./build/index.html shows blank page?

Tags: reactjs

I've written a small react app to test the `build` command.

Simply I didn't change anything after running `npx create-react-app .`
I've only deleted everything inside `./src` folder as usual, and created `./index.html` and `./components/App.js`

and after that I ran the `npm run build` command, and here is the files tree:

```
  .
├── build
│   ├── static
│   │   └── js
│   │       ├── 2.cc830c28.chunk.js
│   │       ├── 2.cc830c28.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt
│   │       ├── 2.cc830c28.chunk.js.map
│   │       ├── main.c49fc855.chunk.js
│   │       ├── main.c49fc855.chunk.js.map
│   │       ├── runtime-main.900dd88b.js
│   │       └── runtime-main.900dd88b.js.map
│   ├── asset-manifest.json
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   └── App.js
│   └── index.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── README.md
```

Now, what I've done is to go to `./build/index.html` file, and trying to open it inside the browser, --> **nothing? blank page? why?**

- but if you normally run npm start and navigate to `localhost:3000` in the browser, you'll see everything working.
- and if you `npm i -g serve` from inside `./` directory and then ran `serve ./build` and then navigate to `localhost:5000` you'll see your `./build/index.html` file working and everything shows up normally.

so what is the magic with `serve`, why I need to **serve** the file in order to render the content on the screen? why I can't just open `./build/index.html` file?

just for the curios folks,

## ./src/index.js:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

## ./src/components/App.js

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello From React App
        </div>
    )
}
```

Some people suggested to add the "homepage" property inside the `./package.json` file, but I need instructions on where to put it and how?

Comment: What's the content of `index.html`?

Comment: for the both ./public and ./build ones, I didn't change anything, they're purely generated by create-react-app

Comment: @AlexIronside, _Can you explain a little in detail about where to write ("homepage":"file:///<path to build directory") statement and how to give the path_

Comment: Oh I don't know. I just found this while searching for an answer. There is some sort of explanation in the answer

Comment: I've found it, you'll put the homepage property in the first level of the object in the package.json file, and you'll set the value of it as the absolute path to the build directory without adding a "/" at the end of the path, eg:`"homepage": "C:/Users/SomeOne/Documents/tests/my-react-app/build"`